# Technical analysis: Candlestick Charts

Tags: technical-analysis, reuters

What does  hollow green, full green, hollow red, full red  candlesticks represent in the following chart? I know red candlestick appear when  closing price is lower than opening price of the stock and green candlestick appear when closing price is higher than the opening price.
[image: Candlestick chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solid or Hollow**
Solid candle if the current closing price is lower than the current opening price.
Hollow candle if the current closing price is higher than the current opening price

**Green or red**
Green candle if the current closing price is higher than the previous closing price.
Red candle if the current closing price is lower than the previous closing price.

Sources:

[https://www.multicharts.com/trading-software/index.php/Hollow_Candlestick_Chart#:~:text=A%20candlestick%20with%20a%20hollow,is%20lower%20than%20the%20open](https://www.multicharts.com/trading-software/index.php/Hollow_Candlestick_Chart#:%7E:text=A%20candlestick%20with%20a%20hollow,is%20lower%20than%20the%20open).

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/how-to-read-hollow-candlesticks/